# Como excluir o último registro de uma tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estava usando o seguinte código no mysql:

```
delete from aluno where id=(select MAX(id) from aluno);
```

Mas aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'aluno' for update in FROM clause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como o rray falou, não é possível, mas há alternativas...
Uma alternativa, seria usar variáveis:

```
set @val_max = (select max(id) from aluno  );
delete  FROM aluno  where id = @val_max;
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Qualquer dúvida, deixa um comentário.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível efetuar uma `DELETE` com um subquery especificando a mesma tabela, conforme diz a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html).

> You cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ordenar pelo Id da tabela exemplo

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY the field DESC|ASC
```

Comment: A cláusula `ORDER BY` não se aplica a `DELETE`. Se isso funcionasse, iria simplesmente deletar todos os registros da tabela.