# You can't specify target table 'pessoa' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

Estou testando o funcionamento de um subquery (subconsulta) e ao executar o comando abaixo:

```
DELETE FROM pessoa
WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM pessoa 
             WHERE id=2
             );
```

acontece o seguinte erro:

> You can't specify target table 'pessoa' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Por que não faz apenas `delete from pessoa where nome='isac'`?

Comment: Por que eu queria testar o funcionamento de uma subquery, sacou?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como excluir o último registro de uma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146330/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Como descrito na documentação do [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html):

> *You cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.*

Ou seja, você não pode excluir registros da mesma tabela que utilizou em uma sub-query. E nem faz sentido fazer isso, pois se é para excluir com a condição `nome = 'isac'`, então bastaria fazer:

```
DELETE FROM pessoa WHERE nome = 'isac';
```